# Change theme colors based on custom value

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I'm using metronic theme for my angular application. I want users to have the ability to choose their own colors. I am unable to figure out how to programmatically change theme colors in my components. I want to get the colors from a database against logged in user, and then apply those colors to the application when they sign in to their account.

Comment: I think the better way is to bind a class to your body when you grab the value from database, and change colors in your css.

Comment: But how I can define a class for each color? There are hundreds of colors and their combinations. @lovis91

Comment: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/build-truly-dynamic-theme-with-css-variables-539516e95837

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by using `css` variables. 
I assume that you are using `sass/scss` and you have your own color variables. 
In your file that contains your `color vars` you could do that:

```
:root{
  --my-theme-color: #ff0000;  //yup it's red
}
$myThemeColor: var(--my-theme-color);
```

In your app at the  `<head>` you could add a new `<style>` tag and change the `css variable` there.
*example:*

```html
<style>
:root{
  --my-theme-color: #0000ff;  /* now it's blue */
}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Wouldn't using JS to change the variable be better than using another `<style>` as you wouldn't be required to pay heed to the order of the `<style>`s?